# How to find how long it takes to perform varoius mundane actions?

Tags: simulations, realtime, time

I was thinking of making a sims game of sorts. I've decided I'm going to have a 'round robin' system for time, rather than having all actions take up the same amount of time. However, I would need to find the time frame for various actions.

I would need times for all manner of mundane actions, like eating meals, getting dressed, bathing, cleaning, you get the idea. Problem is some of these actions should take more or less time depending on the individual's characters stats, such as how active they are, or even their age. How on earth could I ever find such numbers? I could time myself, yes, but that would only give me times for a character just like myself. How can I find the times for all manners of different types of people? Do I need to just look up someone playing a real sims game and copy the time frames the actions take in that game?

Comment: This sounds like a question to ask someone who studies people's daily activities, like a sociologist, not a game developer. Just because you plan to use the information in a game does not mean that game developers are the experts who will know the most about it.

Comment: Then where on stack exchange could I ask this?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a StackExchange site for this — we don't cover every possible topic. I'd search sociology journals for studies into how people spend their time, like time diaries, experience sampling, etc.

Comment: My question is about how to find this info. I wasn't expecting someone to give me the answer. How could I do my own research into this?

Comment: Is it even meaningful for your game to have the exact time per task? Taking a time compression into account of something like 1min per 1h, a toilet break would be something like 5s - too short to fit a good animation or interaction for the player.

Comment: I just told you how you can do your own secondary research using the available literature. If you want to do your own primary research, again, you'll want to talk to an expert in that type of research: a sociologist. They'll be better positioned to advise on how to gather that data. Here on Game Development, we can help you with the game coding / setup / etc. aspects.

Comment: @Zibelas. Yes, it does matter. I thought about having the game work in 15-min intervals (its turn-based), but I didn't like most actions taking at least 15 minutes when there's plenty of actions that clearly wouldn't take that long (besides, it hards to think of anything that wouldn't be exactly one or two turns). Also, the game will be text-based, so there's no 'animations'. As for the sims, taking a bath took about half an hour of in-game time (or 30 seconds in real time), but I can't remember the times for anything else (nothing took nearly as long as a bath, outside of crafting anyway).